# Asp.net core (global.asax) equivalent file

Tags: asp.net-core

If I only want code to executed once for a session where in asp.net core should that go like in asp.net it will be in the global.asax file. I basically want to set a session variable only once in asp.net core, this i would normally do in the global.asax in a traditional asp.net project

Comment: global.asax is an HTTP Module. HTTP Modules are replaced by middleware : https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11869#issuecomment-481097007

Answer (score 0):

`executed once for a session where in asp.net core should that go like in asp.net it will be in the global.asax file` means you wanna have similar method like code below.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){}
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

But just like you know in asp.net core there's no Session related operation like it. So my idea on your scenario is writing a [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to intercept request and write your business in it.